# When running JBoss as a windows service, the path changes to wrapper executable directory folder so relative path references in the code does not work

Tags: windows, jboss

I am running JBoss as a windows service using Tanuki software. When running as a windows service, the path changes to a directory where wrapper.exe is present. The relative path used in the code is relative to that directory and not JBoss home. How can I fix this problem without having to provide absolute paths in the code?

Comment: You should *not* use relative paths when running inside an container, when referring to resources outside of the container. It's a bad idea, because this is what happens. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: I am actually referring to a resource with in JBoss. But since JBoss is running as a windows service, the relative paths are no longer valid. I would like to know how I can preserve the base path to be JBoss home while running JBoss as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss defines quite a bunch of properties for various path, that you can use. 
Look at boot.log to see them:

```
12:29:51,581 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: /im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default
12:29:51,581 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/
12:29:51,581 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: /im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/log
12:29:51,581 DEBUG [Server] Server Data Dir: /im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/data
12:29:51,581 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: /im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/tmp
12:29:51,582 DEBUG [Server] Server Config URL: file:/im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/conf/
12:29:51,582 DEBUG [Server] Server Library URL: file:/im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/lib/
```

and then later in the file

```
12:29:52,015 DEBUG [ServerInfo]     jboss.home.url: file:/im/dev-container/jbossas/
12:29:52,017 DEBUG [ServerInfo]     jboss.server.temp.dir: /im/dev-container/jbossas/server/default/tmp
12:29:52,017 DEBUG [ServerInfo]     jboss.lib.url: file:/im/dev-container/jbossas/lib/
```

and so on.